# Error handling with Spring and Jackson

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

I have problems with generating proper error messages with Spring and Jackson. Scenario: A controller with a custom model a `@ResponseBody` (see below) a model with two attributes, that can possibly cause parsing errors. Now, I want to return a proper error message, if parsing of these fields fails (e.g. Got an invalid string for a `Date`).

If a parsing error happens, Spring will catch it and returns a `400 Bad Request` response with HTML body. Though I am able to implement my own `HandlerExceptionResolver`, that catches this kind of exception to generate a meaningful error message. Unfortunately, I am only able to catch the first parsing error and not a possibly second one.

So, is there a way to collect all parsing/deserialization errors and generate a proper error message with all problems?

I am using Jackson 1.7.1 and Spring 3.2.2.

---

**Some example code:**

*TimeController.java*

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/time")
public class TimeController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    TimeDocument create(@RequestBody TimeDocument entity) {
        // magic
        return entity;
    }
}
```

*TimeDocument.java*

```java
public class TimeDocument {
    public String name;
    public Date date1;
    public Date date2;
}
```

---

*Request 1:* I will get an `200 OK`.

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "date1": 123,
  "date2": 1234
}
```

*Request 2:* I will get an `400 Bad Request`, but I am able to generate a proper error message like: "Date 1 has an invalid format.".

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "date1": "crap",
  "date2": 1234
}
```

*Request 3:* I will get an `400 Bad Request`, but I am not able to generate a proper error message like: "Date 1 has an invalid format. Date 2 has an invalid format.".

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "date1": "crap",
  "date2": "crap"
}
```

Comment: Since I didn't find an adequate solution, yet, I am going to find another way solve my problem. (eg. a second client validation)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you will better need to use `Spring MVC Form Validation` or just validate `input` values at client side using `jquery.validate` plugin (I am just assuming you are using `jQuery` because of `@ResponseBody` usage).

Otherwise, another solution that came to my mind is to implement something like this:

*(First of all, add a `getter` and `setter` for a new `field` in your `entity` called `message` that will store the validation result).*

**Then:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/time")
public class TimeController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String create(@RequestBody TimeDocument entity) {

        String json = null;        

        try {

            //1. Create 'jackson' object mapper
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();  

            //2. Capture data from your entity
            String name = entity.getName();
            Date date1 = entity.getDate1();
            Date date2 = entity.getDate2();

            //3. Validate 'name', 'date1', 'date2' with some regex (a possibility) or any method you want.

            //4. Suppossing that you implemented a method like this to validate your 'bean' or 'dto' that returns 'boolean'
            if(!validate(entity)) {

               //5. If everything is not according to your validation rules, set a message to your entity.
               entity.setMessage("There was an error in the input values.");
            }

            //6. Convert your 'bean' or 'dto' as 'json' string
            json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(entity);            

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //handle the Exception
        }

        return json;
    }
}
```

Now, at client side (suppossing you are using `jQuery` `ajax` or just `$.post`).

Do the following in the `callback`:

```
(..), function(data) {
   if(data != null) { //Callback is not null

      //Parse the 'String' result from 'Controller' as 'JSON' from 'Jackson'
      var obj = $.parseJSON(data);

      if(obj.message != '') {
         alert(obj.message) //An error ocurred in the validation.
      } else {
         //Show the data
         alert('Name: ' + obj.name + ' Date1: ' + obj.date1 + ' Date2: ' + obj.date2);
      }
   }
});
```

So, if there is no `message` present in the `entity`, that means that there is no `error` present. I will suggest this and also consider what I wrote in first lines to have a really good validation at `client` and `server` side.

Comment: This might be an idea, but it looks like hacking. Although, I will play around with this idea.

Comment: @SvenWalter Ok, just let me know how it goes and if you think this is your answer don't forget to check it.